How to Learn Solana Blockchain as a MERN stack developer
I want to learn Solana blockchain development where to start?

@jimii's answer is great, but to add, from another person who has also worked with Mongo / Express / React / Node:

You will be familiar with browsers sending requests to HTTP handlers in Express. In Solana, instructions are sent to instruction handlers in Solana programs, via the program's address. Instead of sending a response, the instruction handlers write their changes to the blockchain to be read back. Multiple instructions to different programs and different functions are bundled in a single transaction, and all instructions must complete for the transaction to make any change.

In React, you have a 'Wallet Adapter' which gives you the 'Connect Wallet' you've seen on Jupiter, Mango, etc. Use create-solana-dapp to set this up quickly.



Check out these courses that cover everything in the Solana development journey

https://www.rareskills.io/solana-tutorial

https://www.soldev.app/course

https://learn.calyptus.co/learn-solana/

https://www.risein.com/courses/build-on-solana


Check out developer guide on the Solana docs website. You can filter based on your experience and search for specific topics

https://solana.com/developers/guides

If you are a visual learner, Nick from the Developer relations also has a wonderful course on the same

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLilwLeBwGuK6NsYMPP_BlVkeQgff0NwvU

Freecodecamp also have a solana tutorial

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/solana-curriculum/

